# Saving GridView state in a Fragment (Android) on Back Button

Tags: android-fragments, android-gridview, android-adapter, savestate

In my android application, I am switching between the two set of images-(Set1, Set2) displayed in a GridView-A inside a Fragment-A.I am doing this on a button press using a boolean variable. Clicking on any GridView icon leads to another Fragment-B. The problem is when I press back button on Fragment-B , the Fragment-A is always loaded with the images of Set1 by default. I want the same set of images (Set1 or Set2 ) to be loaded on FramentA that were displayed before going to FragmentB.

EDITED:
**Fragment Code**

```
  public class GridViewFragment extends Fragment {

    Context context;
    GridView GridMenu;
    GridViewAdapter ga;
    Button Btn_Settings;
    Button Btn_lang_Ch;
    Button favoriteDuas;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //fragment = new GridViewFragment();
        if (view == null) {
            context = inflater.getContext();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gridview, container, false);
            ga = new GridViewAdapter(context);
            Btn_lang_Ch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.lng_ch);
            Btn_Settings = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_settings);
            favoriteDuas = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_favorite_duas);
            GridMenu = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
            GridMenu.setAdapter(ga);

        } else {
            // remove view from previously attached ViewGroup
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            parent.removeView(view);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Btn_lang_Ch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ga.changeImages(!ga.imageSetChange);
                ga.Lang_Status();
            }
        });

        GridMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,  long id) {
                ((MainActivity) context).loadSingleDuaFragment();
            }
        });

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

**GridView Adapter**

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public boolean imageSetChange = false;
    public static boolean curr_lang = false;//english

    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.eng_pic1, R.drawable.eng_pic2,
            R.drawable.eng_pic3, R.drawable.eng_pic4,
            R.drawable.eng_pic5, R.drawable.eng_pic6,
            R.drawable.eng_pic7, R.drawable.eng_pic8,
            R.drawable.eng_pic9, R.drawable.eng_pic10,
            R.drawable.eng_pic11, R.drawable.eng_pic12,
            R.drawable.eng_pic13, R.drawable.eng_pic14,
            R.drawable.eng_pic15, R.drawable.eng_pic16,
            R.drawable.eng_pic17, R.drawable.eng_pic18,
            R.drawable.eng_pic19, R.drawable.eng_pic20,
            R.drawable.eng_pic21
    };

    public Integer[] mThumbIds1 = {
            R.drawable.urdu_dua1, R.drawable.urdu_dua2,
            R.drawable.urdu_dua3, R.drawable.urdu_dua4,
            R.drawable.urdu_dua5, R.drawable.urdu_dua6,
            R.drawable.urdu_dua7, R.drawable.urdu_dua8,
            R.drawable.urdu_dua9, R.drawable.urdu_dua10,
            R.drawable.urdu_dua11, R.drawable.urdu_dua12,
            R.drawable.urdu_dua13, R.drawable.urdu_dua14,
            R.drawable.urdu_dua15, R.drawable.urdu_dua16,
            R.drawable.urdu_dua17, R.drawable.urdu_dua18,
            R.drawable.urdu_dua19, R.drawable.urdu_dua20,
            R.drawable.urdu_dua21

    };
    private Context mContext;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View MyView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.menuitem, parent, false);

        } else {
            MyView = (View) convertView;
        }
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        if (imageSetChange) {
            iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds1[position]);

        } else {
            iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        }

        return MyView;
    }

    public void changeImages(boolean change) {
        this.imageSetChange = change;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        //   gf.Lang_Status();
    }

    public void Lang_Status() {
        // if curr_eng
        if (!curr_lang)
            this.curr_lang = true; // change to urdu
            // if curr_urdu
        else
            this.curr_lang = false;   // change to english

    }

}
```

EDIT:
**MainActivity**

```
public void loadGridViewFragment() {
        if (activityActive) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(GridViewFragment.TAG)!=null){
                ft.replace(R.id.fl_view, frag,GridViewFragment.TAG);
            }   
            else
            {
            frag = new GridViewFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.fl_view, frag,GridViewFragment.TAG);
            }
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

So, can anybody help me out regarding what should be done to load the previous set of images on coming back to gridview fragment instead of having the default images of Set1.

Comment: Like i said, you are creating whole view whenever onCreateView is called. In process of creating view you are always creating new adapter which leads to default image set. Debug your code and check when onCreateView is beeing called. You should definitly not create gridview in every call of onCreateView. You should return previous view if it exists and call setRetainInstance in your onCreate method of fragment.
Debug your code and check if onDestroy is beeing called (if everything is ok it shouldnt be called) in previous fragment when moving to next one.

Comment: see the edited.. onDestroy is being called when clicking on Gridview item to move on to next fragment.

Comment: please post code how are you adding fragment to fragmentmanager. Do you check if fragment exists in fragmentManager?

Comment: I have posted. 
How can we add an existing view of fragment in fragment transaction ?

Comment: insted of creating fragment every time, check if it exists in fragmentmanager like this: getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(GridViewFragment.SOME_STATIC_STRING_TAG)
if it doesn't exists then call new Fragment, else add existing one to transaction...
and when adding it: ft.replace(R.id.fl_view, frag, GridViewFragment.SOME_STATIC_STRING_TAG);

Comment: I tried what you said, its still not working. Please see what am I doing wrong?

Comment: please see the changes made in MainActivity. 
OnDestroy is still being called when moving to the next fragment. Can't we prevent onDestroy from being called?

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(GridViewFragment.TAG) is also null.